# Finding closest jQuery sibling of given type

Tags: jquery

`#getIt` will always be a sibling of `#clicked`, however, `#getIt` doesn't really have an `id` attribute, and one is just included for this posts benefit.

Starting at `#clicked`, what is the cleanest way to select `#getIt`?  I am sure I could do so using two `next()` or `parent()` and `children()`, however, thought maybe a single method is available.

```
<div>
    <table><table>
    <button id="clicked">click</button >
    <p>bla</p>
    <table id="getIt" class="myTable" data-id="123"></table>
    <p>bla</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use an `id` in this question, if you don't really have one? It makes the question confusing, because obviously looking for an element by `id` can be done with `$('#getIt')`. Why don't you use the class `myTable` in the example?

Comment: @trincot  I used `id` just so I can explain which element I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the nearest next element with the selector you specify, then use [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/). To get the nearest of all matching next elements, add the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-class selector:

```js
$('#clicked').click(function () {
    $nearTable = $(this).nextAll('.myTable:first');
    $nearTable.css({ background: '#f00' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <table class="myTable" data-id="123">
        <tr><td>before</td></tr>
    </table>
    <button id="clicked">click</button >
    <p>bla</p>
    <table class="myTable" data-id="123">
        <tr><td>color me</td></tr>
    </table>
    <p>bla</p>
    <table class="myTable" data-id="123">
        <tr><td>last</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks trincot.  Many ways to skin this cat!  Do you like this solution more than jibe's?

Comment: They are different. As you wrote in your question *"starting at #clicked"* I thought you wanted the nearest *following* the clicked button. `siblings` will give you matches from all children, also those that precede the button, starting with the first matching child from the parent, without regard to the proximity to the clicked button. That's why I added some similar tables before and after the button in my snippet, so you would see the difference.

Comment: Agreed.  Thank you

Comment: another solution : ``$(':enabled ~ .mytable:first') .css( "background", "red" )``

Comment: @jibe, if there are more buttons among the siblings `:enabled` will always select the first button. It is not the same thing as starting at the *clicked* button.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) :

`$('#clicked').siblings('table.myTable')`

Comment: Ah, I think this is what I wanted, but it probably should be `$('#cliked').siblings('table')`

Comment: As stated, `#getIt` doesn't really have an `id` attribute.  `siblings()` does exactly what I asked, however, I "should" have stated that I only one the first match following the clicked element.  Can `siblings()` be used such?

Comment: `$('#cliked').siblings('table.myTable')` works perfect.  Thanks!